# how to restrict single modal dialog to portrait mode only in ionic for all platform

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic/cordova . In that i have to restrict single modal in portrait view only. Because that modal not working in landscape mode. 
Is it possible to restrict . Suggest your solution.